# Unity 2d У меня счет очков идет не до бесконечности, а только до 9 а после он обнуляется и не идет подскажите что делать

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я новичок в Unity и много чего не понимаю, я хотел сделать систему очков но у меня код плохо работает, если еще поможете скажите как сделать чтобы у меня счет был поверх всех и его закрывали желтые трубы. https://youtu.be/xDUAZ5mfgsU вот ссылка на видео

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int score;                                    
    public Text scoreText;

    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Score")
        {
            score++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

хз попробуй площадь длля текта увеличить или скачай скрипт отсюда https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yzx8eRtolHk

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/830673)